how to use map reduce chain type with gemini models using chatgooglegenerativeai
model_name == "GEMINI-1.5-FLASH":
        model = ChatGoogleGenerativeAI(model="gemini-1.5-flash",
                                       google_api_key=GOOGLE_API_KEY,
                                       temperature=0,
                                       top_p=0.95
        )


I'm using custom callback function to get streaming responses by appending token by token in a queue. on_llm_new_token using this event. As chatgooglegenerativeai does not have streaming parameter which I can set to True, so how should I get streaming responses from Gemini models using map reduce chain_type. I'm using langchain's default map_reduce chain for this?
Can anyone help me with this?
.invoke(), .stream(), .run()
I tried using this for calling gemini
map_reduce_chain = load_qa_chain(model, chain_type="map_reduce")              
 data = map_reduce_chain.invoke({
                    "input_documents": new_docs,
                    "question": query,
                    "prompt": HTML_PROMPT_TEMPLATE.format(context=total_text, question=query)                 
                   
                })

I'm getting the answer in data['output_text'] but not able to stream the answer token by token
